# How to combine arrays and repeat first array's elments as many times as the length of the second array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The challenge is to build a table. So, the first array is like to the following:

`[1001,235689,1002,235690,1003,235691]`

The second array is like this:

```
[
[tecido,1,Crepe Georgette,,,,mt,0.9,11.9,10.71],
[tecido,2,Forro,,,,kg,0.5,7.916666666666667,3.9583333333333335],
[aviamento,5,Tag Láureen Instrução Lavagem,,,,und,1,0.5,0.5],
[aviamento,3,Entretela malha,,,,und,1,10,10]
]
```

How can I concatenate them to be like:

```
[
[1001,235689,tecido,1,Crepe Georgette,,,,mt,0.9,11.9,10.71],
[1001,235689,tecido,2,Forro,,,,kg,0.5,7.916666666666667,3.9583333333333335],
[1001,235689,aviamento,5,Tag Láureen Instrução Lavagem,,,,und,1,0.5,0.5],
[1001,235689,aviamento,3,Entretela malha,,,,und,1,10,10]
]
```

I've tried looping over the first array and get the second in, but I get lost repeating the first array's elements as many times as the elements count in the second.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I see no connection between the question and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I think this is what you are asking

```
function myfunk1() {
  const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];//create a table with row length of a
  const g = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  const h = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','h','i'];
  let b = [];
  b.push(a);
  Logger.log('With Just A: %s', JSON.stringify(b));
  let c = [...Array.from(new Array(a.length).keys(), x => x)];//creates another array of length a
  b.push(c);
  Logger.log('With a and c: %s', JSON.stringify(b));
  let d = [...Array.from(new Array(a.length).keys(), x => '')];//creates another array of length a
  b.push(d);
  Logger.log('With a and c and d: %s', JSON.stringify(b));
  let e = [...Array.from(new Array(a.length).keys(), x => g[x] ? g[x] : '')];//creates another array of length a
  b.push(e);
  Logger.log('With a and c,d and e: %s', JSON.stringify(b));
  let f = [...Array.from(new Array(a.length).keys(), x => h[x] ? h[x] : '')];//creates another array of length a
  b.push(f);
  Logger.log('With a and c,d and e: %s', JSON.stringify(b));
}

Execution log
2:29:57 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:29:56 PM  Info    With Just A: [["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]]
2:29:56 PM  Info    With a and c: [["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
2:29:56 PM  Info    With a and c and d: [["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],["","","","","","",""]]
2:29:56 PM  Info    With a and c,d and e: [["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],["","","","","","",""],["a","b","c","d","","",""]]
2:29:56 PM  Info    With a and c,d,e and f: [["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],["","","","","","",""],["a","b","c","d","","",""],["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]]
2:29:58 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from);

I actually enjoyed playing around with this and here's a way to put this altogether into one function.  Well two actually.  One to do the work and the other to call it and provide it with a parameter.

```
function testMakeATAble() {
  let arr = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']]
  makeATable(arr);
}

function makeATable(arr) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  sh.clear();
  let w = arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    if (c.length > a.max) { a.max = c.length; }
    return a;
  }, { max: 0 }).max;//returns width of table
  let v = arr.map(r => {
    return [...Array.from(new Array(w).keys(), x => r[x] ? r[x] : '')];create a row of width w and loads it with data from the input array
  })
  sh.getRange(1, 1, v.length, w).setValues(v);//Plant it into the output sheet
}
```

Sheet0:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| one | two | three | four | five | six | seven |  |  |

Answer (score 3):

You can simply [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the second array returning each array prepended by the first two elements of the first, here creating a single [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) beforehand and spreading it into each array in the map.

```js
const arr1 = [1001, 235689, 1002, 235690, 1003, 235691];
const arr2 = [['tecido', 1, 'Crepe Georgette', , , , 'mt', 0.9, 11.9, 10.71], ['tecido', 2, 'Forro', , , , 'kg', 0.5, 7.916666666666667, 3.9583333333333335,], ['aviamento', 5, 'Tag Láureen Instrução Lavagem', , , , 'und', 1, 0.5, 0.5], ['aviamento', 3, 'Entretela malha', , , , 'und', 1, 10, 10],];

const prepend = arr1.slice(0, 2);
const result = arr2.map((arr) => [...prepend, ...arr]);

result.forEach(a => console.log(a.join(', ')));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer actually for _the question_.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using two elements from the firstArray for each row, you'll need to iterate through it two at a time, which prevents use of most array methods, so a good old for loop:

```
let output = [];

for (let i=0; i < firstArray.length; i+=2) {
  secondArray.forEach(el => {
    output.push([firstArray[i], firstArray[i + 1], ...el]);
  });
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function test_07() {
  try {
    var a = [1001,235689,1002,235690,1003,235691];
    var b = [["tecido",1,"Crepe Georgette",,,,"mt",0.9,11.9,10.71],
              ["tecido",2,"Forro",,,,"kg",0.5,7.916666666666667,3.9583333333333335],
              ["aviamento",5,"Tag Láureen Instrução Lavagem",,,,"und",1,0.5,0.5],
              ["aviamento",3,"Entretela malha",,,,"und",1,10,10]];
    var c = [];
    for( var i=0; i<b.length; i++ ) {
      c.push(a.concat(b[i]));
    }
    console.log(c)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one?

```js
let arr1 = [1001,235689,1002,235690,1003,235691]

let arr2=[["tecido",1,"Crepe Georgette",,,,"mt",0.9,11.9,10.71], ["tecido",2,"Forro",,,,"kg",0.5,7.916666666666667,3.9583333333333335],
 ["aviamento",5,"Tag Láureen Instrução Lavagem",,,,"und",1,0.5,0.5],
    ["aviamento",3,"Entretela malha",,,,"und",1,10,10]];
let arr3 = []
for (let i = 0;i<arr1.length;i+=2){
for(let y in arr2){
let little = [arr1[i],arr1[i+1]]
arr3.push(little.concat(arr2[y]))
}
}
console.log(arr3)
```